# Why am I getting an oracle exception when doing a SOQL query

Tags: soql, oracle

the error I get

```
caused by: System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException:
ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character

select /*gatherSlowStats*/ count(1)
from core.custom_index_value ind
where (ind.string_value like ? ESCAPE '\')
and (ind.organization_id = ?)
and (ind.key_prefix = ?
and (ind.deleted = '0'))
and (ind.index_num = ?)
and rownum <= ?
```

The supposed culprit code according the the exception

```
List<Account> records = [Select custom_field__c From Account where Name
    like :(term + '%') order by Name limit 5];
```

Is there some special sanitising of strings that I need to do to prevent this error?

edit:
Updated my code with the suggestions and ran it with full debug logs

```
String term = '123123\t22%';
System.debug('term: ' + term);
List<Account> records = [Select custom_field__c From Account where Name
    like :term order by Name limit 5];

16:43:42.047 (47502000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[16]|System.debug(ANY)
16:43:42.047 (47519000)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|term: 123123\t22%
16:43:42.047 (47526000)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[16]|System.debug(ANY)
16:43:42.051 (51810000)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[17]|Aggregations:0|select custom_field__c from Account where Name like :tmpVar1 order by Name limit 5
16:43:42.078 (78747000)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[17]|System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character


select /*Apex.Class.myController.doSearch: line 17*/ /*+ ordered use_nl(cft) */
cft.val132 "custom_field__c",
nest."Name",
nest."Id",
nest."RecordTypeId"
from (select *
from (select *
from (select t.name "Name",
upper(t.name) "_SORT_COL_0",
t.account_id "Id",
t.record_type_id "RecordTypeId",
t.account_id repl__0
from sales.account t
where (t.organization_id = '00DN00000003ALJ')
and (t.deleted = '0')
and (t.account_id != '000000000000000'))
where (upper("Name") like ? ESCAPE '\')
order by "_SORT_COL_0" asc nulls first)
where rownum <= ?) nest,
sales.account_cfdata cft
where (cft.account_cfdata_id = repl__0)
and (cft.organization_id = '00DN00000003ALJ')
16:43:42.078 (78880000)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
16:43:42.078 (78964000)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-01424: missing or illegal character following the escape character
```

**update**:

salesforce replied with: Please engage your technical team to overcome this issue

Comment: Can you share the case number where salesforce told you "Please engage your technical team to overcome this issue"? I have a friend in support I'd like to have a look at it.

Comment: Just remove the where clause and make sure the error is happening because of where filter

Comment: Out of interest was the [String.escapeSingleQuotes()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_escapeSingleQuotes) method being applied to the  `term` variable? Ran into this issue today where that was the case.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried this in my development org

```
String term = 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America';
List<Account> records = [Select Active__c From Account where Name like :(term + '%') order by Name limit 5];
```

It works fine for me, is there something odd in your 'term' value?

Some things to try...

Avoid the concatination in the SOQL...

```
String termForSOQL = term + '%';
List<Account> records = [Select Active__c From Account where Name like :termForSOQL order by Name limit 5];
```

Add the following to see 'term' value...

```
System.debug(term);
```

Also try ....

```
List<Account> records = 
   [Select Active__c From Account where Name like :'Burlington Textiles Corp of America%') 
     order by Name limit 5];
```

(e.g. without the variable)

**Bottom Line.** Basically this should not be happening normally, you've encountered a Salesforce platform bug. You should make a small peace of Apex like the above with the value of 'term' hard coded and report the issue to Salesforce support. My guess is there is something special, a special character or so? Also tell Salesforce what your Org Id is.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing that concatenation in a variable instead of doing it in the query.

Comment: makes no difference

Comment: whats the value of term?

Comment: Yeah, the SOQL works for me. Its most likely the value of term

Answer (score 0):

Based on your updated answer where you specify `term` to be `'123123\t22%'`. If you are looking for a literal backslash in the *Account Name* then you will need to escape slashes twice in the `term`:

```
String term = '123123\\\\t22%';
System.debug('term: ' + term); // DEBUG|term: 123123\\t22%
```

This will result in an escaped backslash when passed to the query:

```
List<Account> records = [
    SELECT custom_field__c 
    FROM Account
    WHERE Name LIKE :term
    ORDER BY Name
    LIMIT 5
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error.  The problem was that in my SOQL, I referenced a bad formula field.  The formula was something like IF(ISNULL(*GEOFIELD*),False,True).  If I removed that field from the query, everything was fine (NOTE:  This was not in the where clause...just a selected field).  My solution was to change the formula field to IF(ISBLANK(*GEOFIELD.latitude__s*) || ISBLANK(*GEOFIELD.longitude__s*,False,True).

The general issue I'm suggesting here is that I had a formula problem that the formula syntax check did not catch...or did not anticipate would cause a problem if used in a SOQL query.  So check your formulas!

Hope this helps somebody debug their issues.